# "Cannot open include file: 'ofstream'" error in Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ofstream

I'm fairly new to C++ and when I was trying to compile my project, Visual Studio 2010 Express encountered a fatal error saying "Cannot open include file: 'ofstream': No such file or directory" The source code for one of my implementation files (where I'm experiencing the error) is as follows:

```
#include "Character.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ofstream>

using namespace std;

ofstream characterSave;

// Sets the character's name to what the user inputted
void Character::setName(string name)
{
    // Set characterName to equal what user inputted
    characterName = name;
}

// Output the character's name when called
string Character::getName()
{
    // Return characterName
    return characterName;
}

// Save the user's data to save.dat
void Character::saveToFile()
{
    // Creates new save file
    characterSave.open("character.dat");

    // Writes character's name to first line of save file
    characterSave << characterName << endl;

    // Closes save file
    characterSave.close();
}
```

I've searched around online, and I cannot find anyone else with this problem. Could it be my local copy of Visual Studio Express? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Google for [`ofstream`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ofstream), first [result](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/) shows you need header `<fstream>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need

```
#include <fstream>
```

That's where `ofstream` is declared.